# Why my websocket connection is not sending request?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, polling, socket.io-client

I'm trying to create socket connection like that:

```
 const socketConnection = yield call(io, 'ws://localhost:8000', {
    agent: false,
    timeout: 1, // 1 ms
    reconnection: true,
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
    upgrade: false,
    allowUpgrades: false,
    jsonp: false,
    forceNew: true,
    addTrailingSlash: false,
    path: '/websocket',
  });
```

But it does nothing! (if I change it to polling it will work, put replace ws server with http)
Any idea why?